# Create intake form process with automation for Azure DevOps (ADO)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, power-automate, microsoft-forms

I'm wanting to create an intake form that will create a new work item on a Azure DevOps board. Right now I've got a Microsoft Forms form create and have lightly tweaked the pre-made Power Automate script that is provided for this purpose.

Right now when somebody submits the form a new work item is created with a few text variables from the form incorporated into it and an email is sent to the requestor letting them know the form was submitted.

There's a few features that I want to incorporate but haven't figured out yet:

1. Provide a way for the requestor to attach files to the form and have them appear as attachments in the ADO work item. Such as if there is already some documentation for what is being requested that the implementing team would benefit from having.
2. Include the work item ID from ADO in the email confirmation that is sent back to the requestor.
3. Provide a way for the requestor to check on the status of the work item after they have submitted the request.

Can these things be done using Microsoft Forms > Power Automate > Azure DevOps? If not does anybody have a better solution for creating an intake process that ultimately creates a new item in ADO? Thanks!

Comment: PowerApps will provide a more complete solution for you.